# Use CloudKit Web Services' authentication flow in combination with Zapier

Tags: ios, rest, backend, cloudkit, zapier

I'm developing a [Mac app](https://dailytimetracking.com) that uses CloudKit as its back-end. Some of my users are requesting the ability to ingest and extract data via an automation/integration service such as [Zapier](https://zapier.com). For this, I need to introduce a web API.

I am planning to use [CloudKit Web Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitWebServicesReference/) to access the app's data. This data is user-specific and hence, resides in a private database. As a result, CloudKit requires user authentication as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitWebServicesReference/SettingUpWebServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240-CH24-SW3).

Essentially the user needs to be redirected to an Apple-hosted authentication page. After successful authentication, an authentication token is provided that can be used for data operations. Similar to how OAuth2 works, but different enough to not work with Zapier's (or probably any other similar services) [supported authentication schemes](https://platform.zapier.com/docs/auth).

Who has done something similar? What are my options? I want to keep things as simple as possible and make my web API's implementation as thin as possible.

Thanks.

Niels

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely doable and you are on-track with your thinking. Here's how I envision it working:

1. You could do all of this with a front-end web app (no server-side app needed). I personally prefer [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) but you probably have something in mind already.
2. Your app will need to authenticate the user to CloudKit using the flow you mentioned. I highly recommend you use the [Web Services API](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitWebServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240-CH41-SW1) and not try to wrestle Apple's neglected CloudKit JS API. For this, you are going to need to generate an **API token** in the CloudKit Dashboard.
3. You app would then prompt the user to authenticate to Zapier.
4. You should now have user credentials for both CloudKit and Zapier in place in the user's browser cache (you can save, for example, the CloudKit token to `sessionStorage` and likewise with Zapier).
5. Make API calls to Zapier, pull down the data, and then save it to CloudKit all within your JS app. It's all API transactions at this point. I'm a fan of [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) for making the HTTP requests.

If you are downloading files, transacting huge amounts of data, or doing processor-intensive stuff, you might consider using a server for that work. But if you just need a place to pull and push reasonable chunks of data, I see no reason why you can't do it all in a front-end app.

Alternatively, if you don't want a web app at all, and want to only have the user work in the Mac app, that can be done, too. Just make API calls directly to Zapier from within your Cocoa app. Whether or not this is feasible depends some on how you want it to work.

If you have more specific questions or need help with any of the implementation details, feel free to add a follow-up comment or ask a new question.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer. Ideally, I would like to push directly from the app to Zapier. But I wasn't aware of Zapier supporting this? Don't they require a web API from my end in order to access data? Zapier uses concepts like authentication (to have Zapier authenticate to my API on behalf of a user), triggers (to start workflows based on data obtained from my API), and actions (to access and alter data from my API). How would these concepts work when I don't have an API but solely rely on posting data from my app to Zapier directly?

Comment: I don't have a ton of experience with this, but you should be able to interact with Zapier's web API from your Mac app using `URLSession`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession ... I have done OAuth authentication in a Mac app before. You can usually set a callback URL and specify one that will open your native app. For example: `yourApp://callback?data1=abc&value2=xyz`

Comment: But Zapier's authentication part isn't to authenticate against Zapier, it is to have Zapier authenticate against my API right? Could you point me to (API) docs explaining how I can interact with their APIs?

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answer is mostly correct. I don't know much about CloudKit, but we can talk through what you'd need for it to work.

Let's say you had a simple iOS app that stored contacts. On the iOS side, Apple presumably abstracts the upload and download operations.

If you wanted to make a web viewer for synced contacts using CloudKit, you'd need an endpoint to fetch all rows belonging to the authenticated user (each of which would have a UUID, name, and a phone number). I believe that's possible with CloudKit code Apple provides (but let me know if I'm off base).

Now, we want to integrate with Zapier. Say, a "New Contact" trigger. You make some sort of authenticated HTTP request from Zapier to Apple on behalf of an authenticated user. It gives back a list of contacts and Zapier can trigger on the ones it hasn't seen before. To do that, Zapier needs some sort of user token.

That's where the little front-end page the other answerer mentioned comes into play. If you've got a web page that can surface a user's token to them, they can paste it into Zapier and all of the above becomes possible. I'm not sure what the lifespan of the token is, but hopefully it can be automatically refreshed as needed (rather than the user needing to take any manual action).

I'm not sure if what I've described is possible, but do let me know if it is. It would be huge if it were possible to integrate Zapier and the iOS ecosystem!

---

Edit to respond to comments:

> Zapier won't be able to interact with CloudKit in a way sufficient for me (some minor business logic is needed)

I'm not sure what that entails for you, but it's common to put logic in the Zapier integration to structure data in a way Zapier expects. There's a full Node.js execution environment, so the sky's the limit here.

> I don't think Zapier can authenticate against CloudKit as it uses a non-standard authentication scheme

Once you've got a user's token (described above, which *is* unusual), you will almost certainly be able to use it in requests to cloudkit. Zapier provides a "custom" authentication scheme which lets you do basically anything you want. So unless Apple uses something that `fetch` can't handle (unlikely), it should be fine (once you get the token).

> I would like to push data directly from my app into Zapier and have it done whatever magic the user has configured

This is also probably possible. Zapier ingests data in two ways:

- polling, where Zapier frequently makes a web request, store the IDs of items we've seen before, and act on the new ones. You can read more about that [here](https://platform.zapier.com/docs/triggers#polling-trigger). Assuming you can work your business logic into the integration, this is doesn't require an external server besides Apple's
- webhooks, where Zapier registers a subscription with you and you send new data, on demand, to that address. This would probably require a webserver on your end to handle. It's optional though - you can do polling instead.

Hopefully this cleared it up a bit. Feel free to reach out to partners@zapier.com and reference this question to talk more about it.

Comment: This still very likely requires a web API from my end, as Zapier won't be able to interact with CloudKit in a way sufficient for me (some minor business logic is needed). But even when it can be done directly, I don't think Zapier can authenticate against CloudKit as it uses a non-standard authentication scheme.

Ideally, I would like to push data directly from my app into Zapier and have it done whatever magic the user has configured. But based on my experience so far, this is not what Zapier supports/does.

Guess I will need to introduce my own web API with custom authentication.

Comment: @NielsMouthaan I've edited my answer to reply to some of those questions - I'm still mostly shooting in the dark, but it definitely may be possible!

Comment: Thanks. Will consider them as soon as I start working on this integration. A few comments that came to my head while reading yours:

Comment: I'm not sure your comments posted if you meant them to - SO comments aren't multiline

Comment: Apparently they haven't . Your polling & webhook suggestions still require a web API on my end, something I was hoping to avoid. I was hoping to push data to Zapier directly from my app (hence, posting). That would then trigger some kind of action depending on how the user configured the integration. But I don't think Zapier does this kind of stuff.

Comment: If it works like it does in my head, the least-effort version of this requires a simple frontend to capture the user's token and duplicating your business logic into a [zapier integration](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform), but not a web API (assuming zapier can use the captured token to communicate directly with apple)